# Differentiate GCM Push Messages from same Backend to multiple Apps

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use a library project containing a lot of common code for 2 apps.
The Library also contains a BaseReceiver for receiving the push messages.
Each Project has it's own GCMReceiver, which will handle the messages different.
One Server is sending the GCM Messages to the different apps.
The server sends messages to the specific apps via their different registration ids.

My Problem is, that if both Apps are installed on the device, 
they are both receiving the push messages.

Each app has it's own Registration Id, but both Receivers will be called,
when a push message is send to one of the Registration Ids.

How can i prevent the receiver of the app with the registration id, which isn't the receiver from receiving the push message if both apps are installed?

I can't find anything about this special case anywhere ;-(

Comment: You need to use abortBroadcast() for this. for example, lets say app1 and app2 uses this GCM service. now you want push notification only in app1. so in app1 set priority to highest in manifest file for intent-filter tag. while in app2 give lowest priority for same GCM receiver. So when push notification arrived, it will go first in app1. Now here is the magic. in app1 onReceive method, you need to write "abortBroadcast()". This will prevent to receive same push noti. in app2. Thats it. :)

Comment: If each app has its own registration ID, there is no reason for both of them to receive the message sent to one of them (I tested a similar case - two apps on the same device that even registered with the same sender ID, but each only got its own messages). Perhaps something is wrong in your manifest. Please post your manifest.